# Datatable fixxed column

Tags: javascript, php, html

In a Bootstrap 4.3.1 I use datatable and would like to be able to fix the first column (thead, tbody and tfoot). So scrolling with the horizontal bar I would like to see the first column of the table always.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+4+fixed+table+column+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.